# Showing that $\frac{x^2+2x\cos2\alpha+1}{x^2+2x\cos2\beta+1}$ lies between $\frac{\cos^2\alpha}{\cos^2\beta}$ and $\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin^2\beta}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, quadratics

> If $β$ is such that $\sin\beta≠0$, then show that the expression 
>   $$\frac{x^2 + 2x\cos2\alpha + 1}{x^2 + 2x\cos2\beta+1}$$ always lies between $\dfrac{\cos^2\alpha}{\cos^2\beta}$ and $\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin^2\beta}$.

I tried taking the whole expression as $Y$ and solved until a point I got $$(\cos2\alpha - \cos2\beta)^2 \geq 0$$ 
That, however, does not give me the answer. Can anyone point out where I went wrong?

Comment: Welcome to the StackExchange community. Please include your attempt so, that we can understand from where you went wrong. Also, Please avoid putting the question in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method$\#1:$

Let the expression be equal to $k$

Rearrange to form a quadratic equation in $x$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

Method $\#2:$

Let the given expression $=y$

Find $\dfrac1{y-1}$

Divide numerator & denominator by $x$

Now for real $x>0$ $$x+\dfrac1x\ge2$$

and what happens if $x<0$